# is Google Colaboratory Extensible?

Tags: google-colaboratory

as I know, Google Colaboratory are built on top of Jupyter.
While Jupyter family is extensible (you can create additional modules or extend functionalities on Jupyter Notebook, Hub and Lab)
I cannot find anything regarding how to extend Colaboratory, is it:
- Not extensible ?
- Follow other Jupyter extensible mechanism ?

if it is extensible, pls provide the link so we can learn how to extend it

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do? (Extensibility is a bit too general a concept to provide a precise answer.)

Comment: Lets say my notebook produce excel files, I`m trying to send the result through email. user can configure it using pop up panel
its like the following : https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions